# Перевод правил iptables на язык nftables

Tags: iptables

Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой перевода правил с iptables в nftables.
Задача заключается в том, чтобы фильтровать трафик по содержимому пакета в Netfilter/nftables. Составил правила на iptables:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m string --algo kmp -hex-string "|2e 6d 70 34|" -from 58 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m string --algo kmp --string .mp4 --from 58 -j DROP
```

А перевести на nft не могу. Есть кто может помочь советом или с решением?
Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

судя по отсутствию каких-либо упоминаний в документации, это (пока?) невозможно.

в общем, ничего удивительного, ведь проект nftables покрывает лишь 3/4 возможностей программы iptables:

> [It supports 3/4 of the existing iptables features](http://netfilter.org/projects/nftables/)

Answer (score 1):

Теперь поддерживается https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=48814

man iptables-translate

PS: string он похоже ещё не умеет.